# how to use struct in c

Tags: c, struct, fibonacci

I was trying to write a program to generate  fibonacci such that parent process will call fork and child process will write sequences in shared memory fromwhere parent process will read the sequence and display .I know how to create shared memory but I donot know how to link struct array and shared memory so that  parent display the value after child complete

Comment: Post your code so we can work with something.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) to share some memory between a parent a child process after a fork. It's hard to see what you're exactly trying to do or why you're trying to do it (assuming it's some sort of exercise) so it'd be a good idea to elaborate.

Comment: it is a sort of exercise which required shared memory for parent and child process and child process will generate fibonacci sequences and store to shared memory from where parent will access and display on terminal